# Closing multiple scanners causes problems

Tags: java, object, input, user-input

I have a function being invoked and I want it to keep looping, but when I take in an input to keep going I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at SticksGame.main(SticksGame.java:144)
```

I assume this due to the scanner I am using but I'm not sure why when closing two scanners in the code I get problems. I tried removing one of the scanners closes, but then my code infinitely loops and asks for the same input.

```
public void begin() {
    while (this.numOfSticks > 0) {

        if (player == 1) {
            doNextTurn(this.player);
        } else if (player == 2 && !isAgainstAi) {
            doNextTurn(this.player);
        } else {
            doAiNextTurn();
        }

        if (this.numOfSticks <= 0) {
            if (this.player == 1 && isAgainstAi) {
                // AI won
                incrementHats(true);
            }
            if (this.player == 2 && isAgainstAi) {
                System.out.println("AI loses.");
                // AI loses
                incrementHats(false);
                // System.out.print("Play again (1 = yes, 0 = no)? ");
                // int pA = scanner.nextInt();
                // printHats();
            } else {
                String message = String.format("Player %s: you lose.", this.player);
                System.out.println(message);
                // printHats();
            }
            scanner.close();
            return;
        }
        this.togglePlayer();
        // printHats();
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SticksGame game = new SticksGame();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    game.begin();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Play again (1 = yes, 0 = no)? ");
        if (s.next().equals("1")) {
            game.begin();
        } else {
            s.close();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't close the Scanner** unless you are absolutely sure you wont need it again. Once the Scanner is closed, it can not be opened again within the same application instance.  You would need to restart the application.

Comment: A `Closeable` should ALWAYS be closed at the same level as its opening. Remove the `close()` from your begin() method.

Comment: Scanner is automatically closed and garbage collected when the application closes.

Comment: Where does the scanner in the begin() method come from and where do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing such as `scanner` in `begin()` method. And you don't have to close it if you are closing it in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc of `Scanner.close()`: *"If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked."*

Since `System.in` is an `InputStream` which implements the `Closeable` interface, closing a scanner also closes the `System.in` stream and therefore affects the other Scanner. You get a `NoSuchElementException` if you try to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.close()` will close the scanner itself as well as any underlying closeable objects. And Since `System.in` is managed by the JVM internals, there's no way of re-opening it once it's been closed. You should try to avoid closing any Scanner that wraps `System.in`.